# How can a copied note be identified via the API as a newly created note?

Tags: onenote-api

For the purposes of syncing notes in OneNote with those previously downloaded to the browser's IndexedDb, we do a check (via the API) of each note's `createdTime` and `lastModifiedTime` against our own server-stored `last_updated_time`.
This check works fine for added pages and modified pages, so that we can add new notes to the browser's IndexedDb and modify those already stored in it.

BUT when a page has been created in OneNote by a 'Move or Copy - Copy' operation, its `createdTime` property is *that of the original note*, so it can't be identified as a new note. (It does get its own `lastModifiedTime` and `id` properties, but that's just confusing because we'd expect to find in our browser's IndexedDb a previously downloaded note with that `id` that needs to be updated - and of course there's no such note!)

So, how can a copied note be identified via the API as a newly created note - short of getting OneNote itself modified to give that note its own `createdTime` ;) ?

Comment: Maybe there's some undocumented property that'd enable us to identify a copied note as a newly created note ;) ??

Comment: I guess this behaviour is expected, similar to what you see if you simply copy a file or move a file around in your file tree.
In my environment I programmatically add a timestamp to the title of each Notes page to indicate when they are created.
I couldn't find a user definable tag that could be edited to store this information unfortunately.

Comment: @codeye Thanks for your comment. Our use case is rather different, however:
1) Our users create and modify notes directly in OneNote itself, so there's no ability to "programmatically add a timestamp to the title of each Notes page" - except by the developers of OneNote itself ;)
2) Copying a note is not the same as copying a file. Certainly, our user who discovered this problem believed (and rightly so, IMO!) that by the act of copying a note she was creating a new note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not say something like, if the id of the page isn't present in the indexed DB, then add it regardless of createdTime?

Comment: Yes, in fact that's what we're now doing, but doing this for each downloaded modified page seems like an unnecessary front-end processing burden when it could simply be handled by OneNote adding a new `createdTime` property, since there's no question that it _is_ a newly created page. I'd regard this as a flaw in the OneNote implementation.